# How to use Parquet in my current architecture?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

My current system is architected in this way.

Log parser will parse raw log at every 5 minutes with format TSV and output to HDFS.  I created Hive table out of the TSV file from HDFS.

From some benchmark, I found that Parquet can save up to 30-40% of the space usage.  I also found that I can create Hive table out of Parquet file starting Hive 0.13.  I would like know if I can convert TSV to Parquet file.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Hive you can easily convert from one format to another by inserting from one table to the other.

For example, if you have a TSV table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE data_tsv
(col1 STRING, col2 INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

And a Parquet table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE data_parquet
(col1 STRING, col2 INT)
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

You can convert the data with:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE data_parquet SELECT * FROM data_tsv;
```

Or you can skip the Parquet table DDL by:

```
CREATE TABLE data_parquet STORED AS PARQUET AS SELECT * FROM data_tsv;
```